# How to differentiate contours with jagged, irregular edges from those with smooth edges?

Tags: opencv

This field contains a few contours with highly irregular, jagged edges that have resulted from thresholding operations:

[image]

Here they are filled:

[image]

Presently the best way I can think of to differentiate these contours from their smoother neighbors is by point density. In the following example, if there are many points defining a relatively small area, the shape is eliminated:

```cs
using OpenCvSharp;

//...

const double POINTS_PER_AREA = 2.0;
var cleanedContours = new List<List<Point>>();
var area = Cv2.ContourArea(shape);
foreach (var shape in contours)
{
    if (area / shape.Count > POINTS_PER_AREA)
        cleanedContours.Add(shape.ToList());
}
```

I'm not very satisfied with this method though, because it often returns false positives and relies on a subjective constant. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: By jagged do you mean the two central ones and top left one?

Comment: @zindarod See my edit above. I think I realize it's hard to come up with a strict definition.  I'm going to give perimeter / points a try instead of area though. I think that makes more sense. But I'm still interested in other suggestions.

Comment: How about fitting an ellipse to a contour and compute the ratio of black to white pixels inside the ellipse. Such as this [example](https://imgur.com/a/lNXOffq). Ellipse fitting example [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/de/dc7/fitellipse_8cpp-example.html).

Comment: I'm going to revisit this when I get a chance, but one idea I was thinking about is using the delta in `FindContour` points or perimeter after an iteration of morphological open 
followed by close. 

@zindarod That's an interesting idea but I think a "smooth" shape may still generate similar ratios to "non-smooth" ones.